# How to annotate optional properties as required after a check

Tags: typescript

I made an auth endpoint in the backend that takes in an sms otp, and if it's for a phone number that is registered, it logs the user in and sends out a response of `access_token` and `refresh_token`, otherwise if the phone number isnt registered it sends out another response.

Once I figure out whether the response logs the user in or registers them by checking if the `access_token` is present in the response in `isLoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified`, I want to store the token if its a `logged in` response. But ts complains at `saveToSecureStore("access_token", data["access_token"])` when trying to access `access_token` since ts still thinks it can be undefined. Is there a way to annotate that if `logged in` then the `access_token` and `refresh_token` are present?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEDOYD2A7J0C8UDeAsAFBRQCGAxhckgPrCoDWE6A-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-01aQusJe2nqkLtvaZQyVYxVstm8sMLU5ZZ5+lQbQgADo-RdXCvxuuNV60q4XpooBA2lhwfOeyK+zjWn6ugHt1zqwgJMUzTCRMwkC5EQcFEnHRHwjEpBEkUcPNMXvIgrQ7IA)

```
type MyResponse = {
  access_token?: string;
  refresh_token?: string;
};

const data: MyResponse = {
  access_token: 'abc',
  refresh_token: 'cba'
}

type LoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified = "logged in" | "phone number verified"

const isLoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified = (
  data: MyResponse
): LoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified => {
  if (
    data["access_token"] === undefined &&
    data["refresh_token"] === undefined
  ) {
    const myStatus: LoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified = "phone number verified";
    return myStatus;
  }
  const myStatus: LoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified = "logged in";
  return myStatus;
};

const saveToSecureStore = (token: string) => {
  // saveing logic
  return token
}

const myStatus = isLoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified(data);
if (myStatus === "phone number verified") {
  console.log('phone number verified')
} else if (myStatus === "logged in") {
  saveToSecureStore("access_token", data["access_token"])
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just return a boolean from `isLoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified`?

Comment: @vera because I like being explicit

Comment: Might as well use an enum (or even use a plain object instead of an enum) for this, then. If you used a boolean you could make a type guard.

Comment: @vera. Interesting, do you mind showing an example of how to use an enum/object to solve my issue?

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained plaintext [mre] I can paste into an IDE to work on this?  Right now I'd have to start defining things like `navigation` and `LoggedInOrPhoneNumberVerified` and hoping they are close enough to what you're using.  Ideally you'd remove the code's dependence on non-native types/values; less ideal but still good is if you keep them but provide definitions/declarations for them.

Comment: @jcalz Heres a repro https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-bzribw?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1304, TS doesnt seem to complain on the code sandbox...not sure why...if it all seems to work on your end then its all g.

Comment: Does the question depend on react?  If not then the [mre] probably shouldn't either.  (And while a link to an IDE is a nice supplement, it doesn't count as an [mre], which needs to be plaintext and in the question itself. It's easy enough for me to edit that in once we have one, but I prefer to let the person asking the question do such edits so I don't worry about making a change the OP disagrees with.)

Comment: Now that I can see it behaving as you describe, I essentially agree with others... TS only supports custom type guard functions that return `boolean`.  There's an open feature request at [ms/TS#46650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46650) which might enable such things, but it's not implemented yet and might never be implemented.  Do you want an answer that says "this is impossible" along with relevant sources?  Or do you want the existing answer that suggests refactoring to booleans?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom typeguard to make sure your Response is valid.

```
type MyRepsonse = {
  access_token?: string;
  refresh_token?: string;
};

type MyValidResponse {
  access_token: string;
  refresh_token: string;
};

function isValidResponse(a_response: MyRepsonse): a_response is MyValidResponse {
    return a_response.access_token !== undefined && a_response.refresh_token !== undefined;
}

const response: MyRepsonse = {
    access_token: 'Hello World', // string | undefined
    refresh_token: 'World Hello' // string | undefined
};

if(isValidResponse(response)){
    console.log(response.access_token); // string
    console.log(response.refresh_token); // string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&downlevelIteration=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEwGcD2A7Z0C8UDeAsAFBRQCGAxhRMsgPrCoDWE6A-AFxTLABOAlugDmAbmKleEAGaTkACwbNWnbn0GjiAXzFFioSLBAA1MgBt+AE0TIwGLPnHkqNeoxbouPAcJ0TpshTdWTzUfLR1iKQBXdApgfgwofmQTcysaW0wIAAoyOllMrC44RBQ7CABKLjyC8qTkQ1TLa0LoQhJSKElgKN50cnyM8oA6SmpaRXcoAEJsXBiLaUEICygAMjWB2qzhyRkaQKV+2fn0Rallix1NYmIKO2AuoazihCQ0LKhcds6ncdcjlwAOQACQgplMqCgAHVULxTBYgQAaKAAelRqm8QigAB8oAslugVo4-Pt5JNglAgbD4aswRDUEC0RivOpcfizoTiURtLciPwpNlkk10jZytltlgKhUfp17phUKYIMNIUIJc8sKNnBMgugKiJmZj1CSoPK0EqVag1ZLlXsAhS9Qb0UbhFogA)

Comment: I'd prefer if `isValidResponse` returned a string of either `is logged in` or `phone number verified` instead of a boolean.